# Не работают правила iptables на VPS

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, blocks

Всем привет. Имеется VPS (OpenVZ) с установленными iptables v1.4.21
Появилась необходимость заблокировать несколько ip которые нещадно парсят сайт.
Добавил правила в iptables, сохранил их, перезагрузил сервер. В итоге получил нечто подобное в /etc/sysconfig/iptables

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Jun 10 16:24:09 2019
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [131:11369]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 31985 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 51985 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -s 176.122.14.0/24 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -s 141.98.82.104/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 10 16:24:09 2019
```

После перезагрузки VPS проверил статус iptables - active

```
# systemctl status iptables
● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since 
...
```

Но правила iptables по блокировке IP упорно отказываются работать. Перезагружал VPS несколько раз, и при статусе iptables - activе в логи nginx продолжают сыпаться запросы от перечисленных IP в iptables.
Никак не могу понять в чем тут дело. Раньше делал подобные операции на выделенном сервере, все работало...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Срабатывает первое подходящее правило, остальные не просматриваются.

```
-A INPUT -s 176.122.14.0/24 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -s 141.98.82.104/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Должны быть выше чем

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Если не хотите пускать эти адреса на веб сервер.